# How to loop through an object in an array to count the element in VueJS?

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I have this array that contains an object which has 4 elements in it:

```
Task 3: [
   {
    "action_3": 1, 
    "action_4": 1, 
    "action_5": 0, 
    "action_6": 0 
   } 
]
```

I have got to this point by doing this:

```
this.Task3 = this.actions.map(item => {
          return {
            action_3: item.action_3,
            action_4: item.action_4,
            action_5: item.action_5,
            action_6: item.action_6
          }
        })
```

For the next part I would like to check many 1's exist - the result should be 2.

This is my code so far:

```
task3Progress() {
      for (const key of this.Task3) {
        const task3length = Object.keys(key).length

        //should print 2 to console
        console.log(Object.values(key).reduce(
        (count, value) => count + (compare === value ? 1 : 0),
        0) 
    );

       //prints 4 to screen
       return task3length 
      }
    },
```

I would like to do 2 things:

1) return a count of `4` for the number of elements that exist
2) do a check for how many `1`'s exits, and return a 2

How do I do this?

Comment: For counting no. of elements, try Object.keys(this.Task3[0]).length and for the second one you can use for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, Hope you will achieve the result.

```js
task3Progress() {
      for (var i=0;i<Task3.length;i++){
       // will print 4 in console
       console.log(Object.keys(Task3[i]).length);
       let values= Object.values(Task3[i]);
       var equaToOne = values.filter(function (item) {
          return item == 1;
       })
      // will print 2 in console
        console.log(equaToOne.length); 
        return equaToOne.length;
      }
 }
```

Below i have attached code snippet too. You can check the result.

```js
var Task3 = [
   {
    "action_3": 1, 
    "action_4": 1, 
    "action_5": 0, 
    "action_6": 0 
   } 
];

//console.log(Object.keys(Task3[0]).length);
for (var i=0;i<Task3.length;i++){
  console.log(Object.keys(Task3[i]).length);
  let values= Object.values(Task3[i]);
  var equalToOne = values.filter(function (item) {
 return item == 1;
})
  console.log(equalToOne.length); 
}// expected output: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out.

```js
var task_3 = [
   {
    "action_3": 1, 
    "action_4": 1, 
    "action_5": 0, 
    "action_6": 0 
   } 
] ;
var key_count = 0 ;
var one_count = 0 ;

var print_keys = function() {
  for(action in task_3[0]){
    key_count++
    if(task_3[0][action] == 1){
    one_count++
    }
  }
  console.log('key_count = ',key_count, '& one_count=', one_count)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="print_keys()">print</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually has nothing to do specifically with vuejs. It’s only basic javascript:

```js
const actions = [{
    "action_3": 1,
    "action_4": 1,
    "action_5": 0,
    "action_6": 0
}];

function countActions() {
    return Object.keys(actions[0]).length;
}

function countOccurences(compare) {
    return Object.values(actions[0]).reduce(
        (count, value) => count + (compare === value ? 1 : 0),
        0
    );
}
```

Then call `countActions()` and `countOccurences(1)`.

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my question to show where I'm at as I didnt know how to adapt would you suggested to where I'm at.